# Memory encryption against memory leaks

Tags: memory, heartbleed

Will memory encryption (or compression) provided by Intel or AMD processors protect against attacks like HeartBleed or similar memory leaks?

Answer (score 7):

No.

Memory encryption enforce isolation between different processes. Heartbleed leaks data from the hacked process. Existing protections, without needing encryption, already prevents heartbleed-like attacks to dump data from other processes.